# Log Administrator usage across domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory, security, windows-server-2012

Our previous IT administrator stuck Administrator account on literally everything (printers that do LDAP lookup for scan to e-mail were all using Administrator account and the password shows up in plain text in the control panel etc.).

I've started moving everything out to sub accounts made for their purpose and think I'm nearly there but what I want to do is log Administrator usage across a temporary period (for example 7 days) just to ensure that there are no rogue devices/services that are going to break when I change the password/disable the account etc.

Is there an easy way to do this (would prefer without having to install some third-party program, but if that's the only option ...)?

Comment: Is this the local Administrator account on computers all set to use the same password, or is this the builtin Administrator account?

Answer (score 2):

What Operating system are you using? if this is a Microsoft Server OS you can enable Auditing of Logon events. this would gather the information you need.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn319056(v=ws.11).aspx